# Rider: Meaning of orange coloured Assemblies in the IDE

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

Below I have small screenshot of my assemblies list for my solution in Rider. 2020.2.3 - what dose the brown/orange dependencies indicate?

[image: Rider Ide assemblies in solution]

From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/File_Status_Highlights.html#views

It would indicate:  #7C7C00 Obsolete - The file should no longer be in your working copy of the repository.

Although this project is has dependant libraries that use the highlighted NuGet assemblies, so they would be needed.

If they are obsolete, how should these assemblies be added to correctly for fill the other project dependencies.

If the colour means something else, then what?

Thank you!

Comment: Assembly files are excluded from version control (git probably).